# php code inside jquery function to read json file

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a `myfile.json`file like this:

```
[{"teamA": {"name": "DAR", "games": "4", "season":"RS", "points": "89"}}, 
{"teamB": {"name": "BAR", "games": "3", "season":"RS", "points": "78"}}]
```

I usually read the `myfile.json`file like this:

```
$mydata=file_get_contents("myjsonfiles/myfile.json");
$decodeddata = json_decode($mydata,true);
```

So that I can use it in php. For example:

```
<?php 
  $teamApoints=$decodeddata["teamA"]["points"];
  $teamBpoints=$decodeddata["teamB"]["points"];
  $totalpoints=$teamApoints+$teamBpoints;
?>
<div class="apoints"><?php echo $teamApoints; ?></div>
<div class="bpoints"><?php echo $teamBpoints; ?></div>
<div class="totpoints"><?php echo $totalpoints; ?></div>
```

Now, the problem. I am very new at javascript functions, and I want to use the constantly changing info of the `myfile.json`file to update the page without reloading it.

Some users gave me the idea, but, as a newcomer, it is difficult for me to implement it:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
   function updatePage() { 
    $.getJSON('myjsonfiles/myfile.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
       });
      jQuery("body").html("");
      $( "<ul/>", {
       "class": "my-new-list",
       html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
   }

setInterval(updatePage, 5000);

</script>
```

As this is incorrect, how could I access to the elements of the `myfile.json` inside js function and use them in php? Or, in case this is not possible, how could I access to the elements of the `myfile.json`file and replace the content of the divs?

Thanks

Comment: The concept is : you will create a ajax call  after some fixed time interval.Through this ajax call system read the the json file & display the result in your html (in this case div) element.

Comment: Yes, but how? Would you tell me how to read a single element of the json file (as in my example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this approach:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   function updatePage() { 
     $.getJSON('myfile.json', function(data) {
     var $string = '';
     var sum=0;

     $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       var x= Object.keys(val);
       sum += parseInt(val[x]["points"]);

       $string +=  "<div class='"+x+"'>"+x+" Points:" + val[x]["points"] +   "</div>" ;

    });
    $string += "<div class='totpoints'>Total Points:"+sum+"</div>"
    jQuery("body").html($string);
  });
 }
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(updatePage, 1000);
   //set your time as per requirement, so that after this time interval data will update automatically   
});

 </script>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Dipanwita Kundu. How could I access to only ONE of the elements of the json file? I mean, in your approach, you do some things for "each" of the data. But I would like to read only one element of the json file, for example val['teamA']['points'].

Comment: I did not read each data. The data check  `teamA` , `teamB` obj. from that obect I fetch only `points`. console.log(data) to get the value of data

Comment: ok, you didn't reach each data, but you check each `teamA, teamB`data. What if you want to reach only `teamB``points`data?

Comment: So you want only TeamB["Points"]? For that case, you need to know the position of "TeamB" in json object. So  instead of `each()` just try `data[1]["TeamB"]["poinys"]

Comment: And how do you do that? `var x=data[1]["TeamB"]["points"]` ?? Why do you need to specify "1" ?

Comment: as  per your file TeamB is 2nd position & object index start from 0 so it is 1st position